# 質問をメタに移行すると、討議タグではなくdiscussionタグが設定される

Tags: バグ, 対応予定, タグ, メタ, 移行

例 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1647/revisions

[discussion](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) は [討議](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e8%a8%8e%e8%ad%b0) の別名（シノニム）に設定されているので、手動でこのタグを使うことはできないわけですが、別サイトから移行してくると [discussion](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) が設定されています。

どのみち移行された投稿はタグを付け直すことが多いですが・・・。

Comment: 関連: [Questions migrated to localized meta sites get the \[discussion\] tag in English even if it's synonymized to the localized tag equivalent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292823/348970)